# Is getifaddrs giving me duplicate network interface addresses?

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am looking for a particular network address using a small snippet like:

```
  char name[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  struct ifaddrs *iflist;
  if (getifaddrs(&iflist) < 0)
    perror("getifaddrs");

  struct in_addr addr;
  for (struct ifaddrs *p = iflist; p; p = p->ifa_next)
    {
      if (strcmp(p->ifa_name, "lo") == 0)
        {
          addr = reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr_in*>(p->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
          if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr, name, sizeof(name)) == NULL)
            {
              perror("inet_ntop");
              continue;
            }

          cout << name << " ---> " << if_nametoindex("lo") << " : " << addr.s_addr << endl;
        }
    }
```

And the output i get is:

```
1.0.0.0 ---> 1 : 1
127.0.0.1 ---> 1 : 16777343
```

I don't understand the first result..this doesnt happen with something like eth# but it does with another interface called bond0. What is this?

Comment: ok minus the reinterpret_cast part...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getifaddr` is non-standard. I suppose you are using it on a linux system. The man page there has the note:

> The addresses returned on Linux will usually be the IPv4 and IPv6
>   addresses assigned to the interface, but also one AF_PACKET address 
>   per
>          interface  containing  lower-level  details  about  the  interface and its physical layer.  In this case, the ifa_data field
>   may contain a
>          pointer to a struct net_device_stats, defined in , which contains various interface attributes and
>   statistics.

You probably should check `ifa_addr->sa_family` if this has the family that you are expecting.